# How to show a 404 page when the hash value does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5, http-redirect

I've a website with fullpage js, in which I've few sections as test.loc#first, test.loc#second, test.loc#third.

In which if someone types, some section that is not existing, suppose test.loc#testingman, I would like to redirect it to 404 page. But I don't see any option in laravel 5.2 for that.

Can anyone show me how to do it.

Answer: 
This event will show when the hash is changed,
`$(window).on('hashchange',function() {`

Comment: "*Can anyone show me how to do it.*" while that is becoming a popular perception of Stack Overflow, it's not how it works - You learn nothing from just asking for answers, so you should show us what you've tried (so we don't re-suggest methods that you already know fail) and what you've done to try and solve this issue yourself. StackOverflow is not ***Free-Coding-4u.com**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashes (anchors) are generally client side. If you want to redirect based on an anchor, you use JavaScript to fetch the anchor. Then you could use XHR / AJAX to check the anchor against a PHP script to ensure it exists, and then redirect accordingly.

Comment: I was just about to write pretty much the same thing.

Comment: On which event I'll check this in jquery?